# How to pass {StandardToken} in sharepoint app using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jsom

I have a sharepoint hosted app, I need to redirect the user from starting page to another page on button click.

I want to know how can I pass all the tokens in [{StandardToken}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163816.aspx). Do I have to manually create these query string or there is any easy way?

Ex: https://server/a.aspx?SPHostUrl=http://server/b.aspx&SPLanguage=en

Answer (score 1):

You can try `document.URL.split("?")[1]` to get the tokens and append it to redirect page url.

Comment: so I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the query string manually. There isn't an easy/build in way.

Answer (score 0):

Script to get the current page URL/pass the query string from the **SharePoint hosted apps**

```
var currentPageURL = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer : document.location;
```

Script to get the current page URL/pass the query string from the **Provider hosted app you can use PostMessage API concept**